Is there a way I can connect to Netsuite ODBC in Mysql Workbench? I already have a Suite Analytics Access role
Is there a way I can connect to a Netsuite ODBC in Mysql Workbench? I already have a Suite Analytics Access role. What are the necessary steps to do this?
Steps I have done:
Downloaded the most recent odbc driver
enter image description here
I have this succesfully connected in ODBC drivers datasources
enter image description here
What would be the next steps? Thank you so much!!
